# Adding a page to the navigation bar in Kibana 4

Tags: html, angularjs, elasticsearch, kibana

I am attempting to add a welcome/intro page to Kibana 4 and need to modify the navigation menu. I have found the navigation source html document at /src/kibana/plugins/kibana/kibana.html but cannot figure out where the tab names are being injected from.

Here is the list code block where the call is being made:

```
<li ng-repeat="app in apps.inOrder | filter:{show: true}" ng-class="{active: activeApp === app}">
    <a ng-href="#{{app.lastPath}}" bo-text="app.name"></a>
</li>
```

Which correlates to the words "Discover", "Visualize", "Dashboard", and "Settings" as shown here:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/content/uploads/2014/10/Screen-Shot-2014-09-30-at-4.07.15-PM.png

I would expect there to be a configuration file, but I can't seem to find it...

Comment: Looking at the combined index file after running the grunt application, it seems that the app variable is created and then assigned the various headers based on the plugins. It's still a little fuzzy, but is starting to become more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a page in Kibana 4.1.1 like this:

- copy `src/kibana/plugins/settings` to `src/kibana/plugins/help`
- remove

  - `src/kibana/plugins/help/styles`
  - `src/kibana/plugins/help/saved_object_registry.js`
  - `src/kibana/plugins/help/sections/advanced`
  - `src/kibana/plugins/help/sections/indices`
  - `src/kibana/plugins/help/sections/objects`

Then I refactored all code inside `src/kibana/plugins/help` (replace `settings` with `help`).

Surely not the easiest way of doing things, and [very much not endorsed by elastic.co](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/blob/4.1/src/kibana/plugins/README.txt). I hope a supported way of doing things will not be too far away.

Comment: And you don't change nothing more? I did this and doesn't work.