# adding a tab and a page inside the tab to kibana 4.1.1

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, kibana-4

I am new to elasticsearch and kibana. I need to add a tab to kibana so when clicking on a tab, my url must be loaded inside it. I downloaded the kibana source package from [here](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/tree/v4.1.1/src) and followed [this instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27807200/adding-a-page-to-the-navigation-bar-in-kibana-4) ,then in order to run kibana, first of all I ran elasticsearch1.6.0. Then copied `bin` and `config` folder of [kibana binary package](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/kibana)
to the root of this source project, also edited bin/kibana file to change  `SERVER=${DIR}/src/bin/kibana.js` to `SERVER=${DIR}/src/server/bin/kibana.js`. 
I found that some packages missed in kibana server package and so `./bin/kibana` encountered errors. I don't know if I follow the correct procedure, if not, so how to edit kibana code and then run it? 
thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for customizing kibana according to your requirements, Then for detailed explanation please go through the CONTRIBUTING.md file here https://github.com/elastic/kibana/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Steps :

1. Clone the kibana repo and move into it

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/elastic/kibana.git kibana
   cd kibana
   ```
2. Install the version of node.js listed in the .node-version file (this is made easy with tools like nvm and avn)

   ```
   nvm install "$(cat .node-version)"
   ```
3. Install dependencies

   ```
   npm install
   ```

4.Start elasticsearch

Note: you need to have a java binary in PATH or set JAVA_HOME.

```
    npm run elasticsearch
```

5.Start the development server.

```
    npm start
```

6. Open your browser and go to 127.0.0.1:5601 (default port) to see kibana running.

Once you start the development server. You can make code changes and see the changes reflecting on reloading the browser.

7. To create kibana binaries. Use this command.

   ```
   npm run build
   ```